# Why did the self=this idiom go wrong in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

Here is my *before* code:

```
...
'postInitialization':function(){
  var S = this;
  $(document).on('click','.myButton',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ix = $(this).data('index');
    S.doSomething(ix);
    });
 },
 ...
```

This has a subtle bug, whereas my *after* code fixes it:

```
...
'postInitialization':function(){
  window.SAVE_S = this;
  $(document).on('click','.myButton',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var S = window.SAVE_S;
    var ix = $(this).data('index');
    S.doSomething(ix);
    });
 },
 ...
```

In both cases the code is used something like this:

```
var S = {
  ...
  'list':[],
  'postInitialization':{...},
  ...
  };
...
S.postInitialization();
...
```

Then later on something adds an entry to `S.list`, e.g. `S.list` becomes `["hello world"]`. Then, after that, `.myButton` gets created in the DOM, and then at some time after that it gets clicked.

The problem in the first case is that in the `doSomething()` function `S.list` is empty. By assigning it to an explicit global, in my fixed code, `S.list` contains the entry I'm expecting. In other words, by using the `var S = this;` idiom it appears to be taking a snapshot of how `S` existed at that point, so misses out on the later change. (NOTE: everything else works, the function call is made, the rest of the `S` data is there, etc.)

Is this something to do with using jQuery's `on()` to attach an event handler to a DOM object that does not exist yet?

And, while `window.SAVE_S` works, it feels crude. Is there a better workaround?

Comment: Are you trying to update the list via the `S` variable? That `S` is only scoped to the `postInitialization` function.

Comment: @Musa, I made an edit, does that make it clearer and answer your question?